# Irreducibility of $\sum_{n=0}^{101}\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

What can be said about the irreducibility of $\sum_{n=0}^{101}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ over the field of rationals?

Multiplying and dividing throughout by $101!$, we obtain the given polynomial is irreducible iff the polynomial $\sum_{n=0}^{101}P_{n}^{101}x^n$, where $P_r^n$ is the number of permutations of $r$ items from $n$ items. The new polynomial does not seem to have a root according to rational root theorem. But, how do we proceed further? I hope it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Any hints? Thankds beforehand.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is your polynomial then $101! f(x)$ is an integer polynomial that satisfies Eisenstein's criterion with $p=101.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Schur's theorem all truncated exponentials of form $\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ are irreducible over rationals, see for example Keith Conrad's blurb [Irreducibility of Truncated Exponentials](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/schurtheorem.pdf) for correct proof. In fact the following more general result is proven there using algebraic number theory:

> Any polynomial 
>   $$1+c_1X+c_2\frac{X^2}{2!}+\dots+c_{n-1}\frac{X^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\pm \frac{X^n}{n!}$$
>   with $c_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Yours is just a special case, although as pointed out in comments/other answer that case can be proven much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ThomasAndrews comment, the problem is straightforward, the modified polynomial $\sum_{n=0}^{101}P_{n}^{101}x^n$ clearly satisfies the Eisenstein criterion with the prime number $101$ dividing all coefficients except the last and the square of $101$ not dividing the leading coefficient of $101!$.

Comment: $101!/n! \ne (101-n)!$. I'm not sure why you are looking at the other polynomial.

Comment: That's not quite right. The modified polynomial is $$\sum_{n=0}^{101}\frac{101!}{n!}x^n$$ The coefficient is not $(101-n)!,$ and the polynomial you've given doesn't satisfy Eisenstein.